# Hide a list in VS

Tags: list, javascript

How can I hide a Custom List programmatically (created the list also programmatically) and create it inside my `Visual Studio Ultimate 2013` so that not all users can tamper it?

I tried creating a list using JS and it stores in `https://MySite/sites/MySiteCollection/Lists/MyCustomList/AllItems.aspx`

But seems to be like a normal SP List, which can be easily modified!

Comment: you can set hidden property to True in list definition Element.xml file

Comment: Could not find an elements.xml when the List got created programmatically! Could you please help me understand it better!

Comment: how did you create your list? share code

Comment: var siteUrl = '/sites/MySiteCollection;
function createList() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
    var listCreationInfo = new SP.ListCreationInformation();
    listCreationInfo.set_title('MyHotelList');
    listCreationInfo.set_templateType(SP.ListTemplateType.genericList);
    var oList = oWebsite.get_lists().add(listCreationInfo);
    oList.set_description('New Custom List');    
    oList.update();
    clientContext.load(oList);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);
}

Answer (score 3):

If you created the list with JavaScript code, you can hide it easily:

```
//var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
list.Hidden = true;
list.Update();
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Note however, that this does not prevent users with "manage" permissions to "guess" the URL https://MySite/sites/MySiteCollection/Lists/MyCustomList, navigate to it so they access and can edit settings for this list.

Comment: I think list.Hidden = true is correct, isn't it ?  But if user can use the SPD, they can still se it.

Comment: Yup, sorry, edited to change `false` to `true` :) Thanks.

Comment: As stated, setting the `hidden` property to `true` does not really prevent the users from accessing the list: ths list is hidden from the UI, but users can still access it if they know the URL or with SPD, or with REST calls, or maybe with other methods. The only thing that can really prevent users from accessing (or editing settings) a list is to set permissions on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting that users should not even try typing url and navigate to the list (even it is hidden) then only option is

- create a SharePoint group,
- add users whom you want this list to be accessible,
- Add jquery on the list page,
- verify if logged in user is not part of that group.
- If he/she is, let he see the list
- else redirect him back to landing page of your site or where ever you want.

If you just want no links to be present on the site, You can use **Evariste's** code block. (Here if users are smart, they can type in url)